# Function that would create a copy of lists

Tags: python

I need to a function that would reset the list to its orginal state so in order to do that I would use the copy of a list as its the most straightforward way to achieve it.

Every time I make changes to a list(or number of lists) I would like to have a list in its orginal state. Since the number of lists can be bigger I need a function that can deal with it without repating several lines of code everytime.

I tried to make a function that would simply create a copy of a list and thus I could use it to get a a copy of orginal list for further alterations.
But there is something that I am missing because im getting error:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=['a','b','c']
list3=[434,52,43]

def copy_lists():
    list1c=list1[:]
    list2c=list2[:]
    list3c=list3[:]

copy_lists()
list1c.append('b')
copy_lists()
#now list1c should be back to orginal 
print(list1c)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-95468ead1e78> in <module>()
      9 
     10 copy_lists()
---> 11 list1c.append('b')
     12 copy_lists()

NameError: name 'list1c' is not defined
```

Comment: ` list1c` is a local variable, only defined inside `copy_lists`.

Comment: Deepcopy will probably do that for you: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html

Comment: Don't (try to) use so many global variables. Take the lists to copy as arguments, and return the copies in a tuple (or another list).

Comment: Can you [edit] this to make it more obvious to a casual reader why it isn't a duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)?

Comment: I added that the main point here is that I needed a function that uses copy aspects of a list and that the function is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you have to be really careful when making copies of objects. If you do `list1c = list1` and `list1c.append('a')` list1 will also have 'a' appended to it. [Here](http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/) is an article talking about when variables are pointers vs an actual copy of the data from another variable.

The best way to make sure that modifying a copy of an object will not change the original is to use the [deepcopy function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) from the copy module.

```
from copy import deepcopy
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = [434, 52, 43]

list1c = deepcopy(list1)
list2c = deepcopy(list2)
list3c = deepcopy(list3)
list1c.append('a')

print(list1c)

# list1 will not be modified if you change list1c
print(list1)
```

The error you are running into now is a scoping problem. When you are trying to use list1c outside the `copy_lists()` function you are trying to access a local variable outside its scope (in this case the copy_lists function). [Here is some reading about scoping in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

If you would like to do the copying in a function here is a way to do it by returning a tuple from the copy_lists() function.

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = [434, 52, 43]


# changed list1 to l1 to avoid having a variable in the inner scope shadow the outer scope
def copy_function(l1, l2, l3):
    l1c = deepcopy(l1)
    l2c = deepcopy(l2)
    l3c = deepcopy(l3)
    return l1c, l2c, l3c


list1c, list2c, list3c = copy_function(list1, list2, list3)
list1c.append('a')

print(list1c)

# list1 will not be modified if you change list1c
print(list1)
```